# Validation of Form Field not in Model Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add a required validation for a form field not in my database model.  Currently in my database model, I have 2 values.

Model:

```
public class Values{
    [Required]
    public string Value1{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want a third value in my Views form that can handle validation, but it does not exist in the database, so should not exist in my Database Model, but I need it for use in the Controller.

View:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value1)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value2)
    </div>
```

How can I add a third field with the same simple validation, but that does not exist in my database?  If not, how can I achieve similar validation?

Example:

```
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value3)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value3)
      </div>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add a third field with the same simple validation, but that
>   does not exist in my database?

This is where viewmodel comes in handy. So you can accept more or less input that does not necessarily (or specifically) mapped back to your model or database. So you can have something like this:

```
public class ValuesViewModel {
    [Required]
    public string Value1{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

You then query the model from your database and map it to that viewmodel. Something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetValues() {
    var values = getFromDb();
    return View(new ValuesViewModel {
        Value1 = values.Value1;
        Value2 = values.Value2;
        Value3 = some_other_value;
    });

}
```

You can then receive it back along with the fields that are in your database and do things with as you see fit.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostValues(ValuesViewModel input) {
    var values = getFromDb();
    // map values back to the model from the viewmodel
    values.Value1 = input.Value1;
    values.Value2 = input.Value2;
    // some logic applied to Value3
    // etc, etc
    // save your model to the database
}
```

Comment: This is making sense, I am going to try it.  Let you know what I find.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you for broadening my horizons von v.

Answer (score 0):

You cant make validation on a property that doesnt make part of a model.
Html.Helper**FOR** creates the html tags for a specific property, if it doesn't exist how do you want to validate it?

If you want to pass a variable to the controller you can just add it at the view with view bag logic behind but im not really understanding what you mean about validating that non-existant value.