# Select List returns System.Data.Entity.DynamixProxies instead of values in MVC asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have got two different tables. User and ProjectDetails. There are two different controllers as well to do CRUD operations on these tables. Now, I have a case where, in the User CREATE operation, I have to select the Project from the List of Projects in ProjectDetails. I tried the following:

In the user model, I created this line:

```
    public IEnumerable<ProjectDetail> ProjectDetail { get; set; }
```

And in the controller, in the create Action, I have added the following code:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new UserDetail
        {
            ProjectDetail = db1.ProjectDetails
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

And in the create view, I am trying to get the list of Project IDs as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.ProjectDetail, new SelectList(Model.ProjectDetail, "Project ID"))
```

However, wen i run, i get the number of lines (as equal to the number of projects) as

System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ProjectDetails_F########### (Some numbers)..

Please can someone help me?

Regards,
Hari

[EDIT] - I checked in the debug mode and found the following.. Tried attaching the image..

I drilled down that Proxy things and found ProjectID there. How can I get that?

Comment: you can map it to a dto first and then send it to the view ..something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579598/c-sharp-mvc-3-using-selectlist-with-selected-value-in-view?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a wrong overload, use this instead:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.ProjectDetail, 
    new SelectList(Model.ProjectDetail, "ProjectId","ProjectName"))
// where ProjectId is the unique identifier field of `ProjectDetail` 
// and `ProjectName` is the text you want to show in the dropdown
```

In your code you are not telling the html helper what properties to use for the `datavalue` and the `datatext`. The overload you use is the one where you tell the htmlhelper which value is selected.

Comment: ROCKING!!!!!!!!!! Please now, could you tell me how to map this to the User field? I got the dropdown. I should map the value selected in the dropdown to the input field in User mode which is Project.

Comment: Do you have something like `User.Project` where `Project` has a field of `Id`? If yest then do `x=>x.Project.Id, new Selectlist`...

Comment: von v - Sorry one more doubt. This was easy in my create action. How could I possibly do this for Edit?

 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new UserDetail
        {
            ProjectDetail = db1.ProjectDetails
        };
        return View(model);
    } 

Now, in the Edit - I have

   public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            UserDetail userdetail = db.UserDetails.Find(id);
            return View(userdetail);
        }

Comment: You do the same thing you did for the add. After you query your object (`Find(id)`) do the `userinstance.ProjectDetail = db1.ProjectDetails`. Also, you might want to consider working with viewmodels, it's better than passing your entities/models around.

Comment: great. Sure.. Will check ViewModel approach.

Comment: I've explained it and gave a simple example just a few hours ago, [see it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311716/validation-of-form-field-not-in-model-class/16311763#16311763).

Comment: Just had the same issue and this has been really helpful. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
var projection = db1.ProjectDetails.Select(t => new ProjectDetailsViewModel
            {
                Prop1 = t.Prop1,
                Prop2 = t.Prop2
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new UserDetail
        {
            ProjectDetail = db1.ProjectDetails.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Try like this@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.ProjectDetail, new SelectList(Model.ProjectDetail, "Project ID"))

Comment: sorry like this

@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.UserDetail.ProjectDetail, new SelectList(Model.UserDetail.ProjectDetail, "Project ID"))

Comment: Looks lik, I have to have a different overload. Please check von v answer. Its working.. :)